# Как проверить то что юзер докрутил до последнего элемента в DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

У меня приложение wpf mvvm, мне надо проверять, докрутил ли пользователь до последнего элемента или он оказался в его в поле зрения, и что то делать в таком случае. Как это реализовать?

Comment: А зачем это всё? Вы уверены, что пользователю будет понятно, что таблица так себя ведёт?

Comment: авто догрузка данных. прочитал 21 строку, пролистал вниз - прогрузилось еще.

Comment: В winForms у dataGridView есть свойство `dgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex`, которое возвращает индекс первой строки, которая видна на данный момент. Добавив к этому индексу количество отображённых строк можно узнать, индекс видимой строки внизу (`dgv.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Displayed)`). Подписавшись на ивент Scroll можно проверять это при каждом скролле пользователя и подгружать, если это действительно нужно. Не думаю, что у DataGrid сильно отличается логика. Конечно, выглядит это, как какой-то костыль, но why not

Comment: тебе наверное вот это надо - https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/14.5.php